# selecting a portion of string in sql and using it to update a column

Tags: mysql

I have three tables

```
products->(id, number, public, custom, etc)
references->(id,ref,product_id,price_id)
product_descriptions->(id,product_id,description,summary)
```

i need to populate the value of the column ref from table references which is an int , using a part of the string description in table product_descriptions , Is this possible?

how to select a particular portion of a string from one column of a table and convert to int and store in a column of a different table?

I am using MySQL

Answer (score 0):

For Transact-SQL (SQL Server, SYBASE ASE,ASA,IQ) you could try this.

Assuming the first 4 characters (starting at position 0 for a length of 4 characters) of product_description are the INTEGER value you wish to store in column references.ref.  Try something like this in T-SQL

```
UPDATE references SET ref = CAST(SUBSTRING(t2.description,0,4) AS INTEGER)
FROM references AS t1 
INNER JOIN product_descriptions AS t2 
ON t1.product_id = t2.product_id
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, the description has no particular format in my case and there can be more than 1 values for ref in one description , but ref has to take each value from the description...